# Materials for building a sound proof home office in a 5 ft x 6 ft x 8 ft cube

Tags: drywall, wood, sound-proofing, plywood, materials

I have a big living room 16ft x 22ft x 10 ft(height). I wanted to take a small corner 6ft x 5ft x 8ft(high) to build a home office. I was initially planning on building a steel cube frame out of 3/4 inch square shaped steel pipes. And then tacking on thick(1/2 inch) sheets of plywood all around. However, while researching online I have found that drywalls may be a better better suited for my use case.

I am looking for the following attributes in this cubicle:

1. Sound proof: I'd like this cube to be as sound proof as possible.
   Since this is a home setting, there would be noise in all
   frequencies. Also, I am open to closing all the 6 sides of the cube
   and installing a small split ac if that is the best way to do this.
2. Robust: I have a son who is 1.5 years old, I don't want the walls to
   fall and cause any injuries.
3. Inexpensive or Mobile: This is a
   rented place, I don't want to spend too much money into this if I
   cannot move/reuse the materials to a new place.

So, my questions are, which material is best for my use case? Steel cage with plywood walls? or Steel cage with drywalls? This is all new to me, so please point me in the right direction :)

**EDIT**:
My primary requirement is to block the sound coming from my home into the cubicle.

[image]

Comment: None of those approaches will get you a "sound proof" room. Perhaps if you explained your needs a little better we could help.

Comment: My primary need is to block the outside noise from coming into this cubicle. I could build 2 walls (that touch the ceiling) using drywall to create an enclosing space if that is the most effective.

Comment: A bit unrelated... 5 ft x 6 ft x 8 ft is not a cube. It has to have the menasures to be a cube.

Comment: Google "acoustic office panels", and/or go to your local University, and check out what they use - I'm sure you will surprised, at how well they work. Some Universities have a "salvage" department, where they sell excess furniture, like this, for a very cheap price. I had some in my basement, for absorbing some of the sound from my drum set - they worked great, looked good, and were literally $5 a pop. They are engineered, for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

How many dB of isolation are you looking for? The ideal would be to isolate the inside and outside from each other, which means offset studs and joists. The walls and floor could be filled with sand to achieve further isolation, if your building structure will handle the weight.... websearch home recording studios,  many if the solutions for those would apply here.

Remember to allow for ventilation; any lighting or PCs in that box will be significant heat sources, and your own body puts out on the order of 100W of heat. Getting airflow without losing sound isolation may be tricky.

Easier solution: a good pair of noise-cancelling headphones may be all you really need.